# provide module, main and browser fields that satisfy esm, commonjs and bundlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, rollup

I have a number of published npm packages that I have upgraded to provide both commonjs and esm builds.  Some of the packages might be for both node and the browser.  All packages compiled with webpack or rollup.  All are written in typescript and transpiled into a `dist` directory.

I create a commonjs `index.js` file that looks like this:

```js
 'use strict'
  
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports = require('./react-abortable-fetch.cjs.production.min.js')
  } else {
    module.exports = require('./react-abortable-fetch.cjs.development.js')
  }
```

I set the package.json `main` field to the above `index.js` file.

I also generate a `.esm.js` file for each package and I set both `browser` and `module` fields to the `esm.js` file and set the `type` file to be `module`.

The end result is something like this:

```json
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "browser": "dist/react-abortable-fetch.esm.js",
  "module": "dist/react-abortable-fetch.esm.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
```

The problem with this approach is that only esm packages can consume it (unless I am wrong).

What is the best way to configure the `package.json` file so that packages that have not made the leap yet (and that is quite a few) can still consume the package?

Comment: You might be looking for https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_dual_commonjs_es_module_packages and https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_conditional_exports . But I don't think bundlers support `exports` yet, so you will probably still need `browser` and/or `module`.

Comment: @FelixKling support is limited and typescript does not support them sadly.  They sound great in theory but not possible in reality

Comment: I wrote a rollup-based project template that generates bundled cjs, esm, and umd builds along with a bundled .d.ts and have been using it successfully for multiple projects. You can check it out here: https://github.com/patrickroberts/template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to leverage Node.js [conditional exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_conditional_exports) to customize the import behavior depending on how you import the module (`require` or `import`).

In order to have two different interfaces for CommonJS and ESM, you could either:

- Transpile to both CommonJS and ESM (allows to accidentally use both `import` and `require` for your library in the same application which could cause unwanted and unpredictable behaviors)
- Have the implementation as ESM and a CommonJS wrapper (not possible because you can't `require` an ECMAScript module when it has top-level `await`)
- Have the implementation as CommonJS and an ESM wrapper (best actual solution)

So you have to set CommonJS as a TypeScript transpilation target, then create an ESM wrapper (preferably in a dedicated folder). Finally, map the CommonJS and the ESM entry points to the corresponding files in the `package.json`:

```
"exports": {
  "require": "./index.js",
  "import": "./esm/index.js"
}
```

I have published a minimal working project here: https://github.com/Guerric-P/demo-commonjs-esm

In order to use the libraries in TypeScript, you also need one `.d.ts` file aside every JavaScript file.

Comment: i have a typescript code base and typescript does not support exports.  they sound great but support is limited

Comment: @Guerric-p how would you write your package.json if you were including CJS, ESM and IIFE (for old-fashioned script tag use) ?

Comment: @rednoyz why would you use IIFE when ESM is supported in modern browsers?

Comment: because not all environments support ESM, even if the browser itself does...

Comment: I don't get it, you want to use a script tag outside a browser?