# Convert a node module to ESM

Tags: node.js, web, es6-modules

My project uses ES6 modules in a browser, but I need to use a library that is made using Node module then webpacked: cytoscape-dagre or cytoscape-klay. Those are extensions for Cytoscape which itself has an ESM port that works just fine. I am finding a lot of resources to go from ES6 to anything else, but not the other way around. Does anyone know where I should look?

Comment: I guess you have to fork these projects and add them an ESM wrapper. I wrote something about it here that you might find interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67250751/provide-module-main-and-browser-fields-that-satisfy-esm-commonjs-and-bundlers/67291120#67291120

Comment: @GuerricP so I tried to make an ESM wrapper as you did in your GitHub, but when I try to import the wrapper in the browser I get an error because the source I import into the wrapper doesn't provide any export ESM style. You're sure your solution isn't only for Node? Did I miss a transpiling step?

Comment: Indeed that doesn't work in the browser, I've answered too fast sorry

Answer (score 0):

There are online services for this, such as `esm.sh`:

```js
import cytoscapeDagre from 'https://esm.sh/cytoscape-dagre';
import cytoscapeKlay from 'https://esm.sh/cytoscape-klay';
```

If you’d like to build it and host it yourself, you could do what `esm.sh` does and use `esbuild`: https://github.com/evanw/esbuild.